# When searching, Prolog gives correct answers but repeats them N times before searching another

Tags: search, prolog, boolean-logic

Ok So i've got this Prolog code that represents an evolving world of blocks, and there's a robotic arm that can move 1 block at the time, and 2 little robots "rob and bor" that can paint blocks of their assigned color when the blocks are on top of a tower or on the bottom of a tower (See code for the conditions). function `clear(X)` is true when block X is on top of a tower, and `ontable(X)` is true when X is on the table (at the bottom of a tower). Single block towers return both `clear` and `ontable` as `true`.
The code aims to give all the solutions, step by step, when asked for a particular state (Like all 4 blocks on a single tower and red painted).
For that, there's a set of actions and facts defined, their conditioning effects (When action A is done under conditions C, what happens to the fact F) and a possibility/reality check with functions `poss`(returns true if some action is possible to do) and `holds`(returns true if some fact is true) that work on every state S. `legal` is the mix of these 2(Something is legal if everything in it holds and is possible).

```
%% Object Declaration (problem-specific)
block(B) :- member(B,[a,b,c,d]).

% colors available for rob and bor
color(rob,B) :- member(B,[blue]).
color(bor,B) :- member(B,[red]).

%% Initial Situation (problem-specific)
holds(F,s0) :- member(F,[on(a,b),on(b,c),ontable(c), ontable(d), clear(a), clear(d)]).
holds(color(B,white),s0) :- block(B).

%% Blocks World Preconditions (domain-specific)
%% action move_to_block(X,Z) moves block X on top of block Z
% poss is true when its possible to do the action.
poss(move_to_block(X,Z),S) :-
    holds(clear(X),S), holds(clear(Z),S), Z\=X, \+ holds(on(X,Z),S).

poss(move_to_table(X),S) :-
    holds(clear(X),S), \+ holds(ontable(X),S).

%% Robot R paints block B of color C

poss(paint(rob,B,C),S) :-
     color(rob,C),holds(clear(B),S), \+ holds(color(B,C),S).



poss(paint(bor,B,C),S) :-
    color(bor,C), holds(ontable(B),S), \+ holds(color(B,C),S).


%% Blocks World Effects (domain-specific)
% is_conditional_negative_effect(Act,Cond,Fact)
% when Act is peformed and Cond holds, Fact becomes false

is_conditional_negative_effect(move_to_block(X,_),on(X,Y),on(X,Y)).
is_conditional_negative_effect(move_to_block(X,_),ontable(X),ontable(X))
is_conditional_negative_effect(move_to_block(X,Z),true,clear(Z)).
is_conditional_negative_effect(move_to_table(X),on(X,_),on(X,_)).
is_conditional_negative_effect(paint(R,B,C),color(B,D),color(B,D)).
% is_conditional_positive_effect(Act,Cond,Fact)
% when Act is peformed and Cond holds, Fact becomes true
is_conditional_positive_effect(move_to_block(X,_),on(X,Y),clear(Y)).
is_conditional_positive_effect(move_to_block(X,Z),true ,on(X,Z)).
is_conditional_positive_effect(move_to_block(X,_),true,clear(X)).
is_conditional_positive_effect(move_to_table(X),true ,ontable(X)).
is_conditional_positive_effect(move_to_table(X),on(X,Y),clear(Y)).
is_conditional_positive_effect(move_to_table(X),true,clear(X)).
is_conditional_positive_effect(paint(R,B,C),color(B,_),color(B,C)).

holds(true,s0). % "true" always holds

holds(F,do(A,S)) :-
         holds(F,S),
         \+ (is_conditional_negative_effect(A,C,F), holds(C,S)).

holds(F,do(A,S)) :-
    is_conditional_positive_effect(A,C,F),holds(C,S).

% S is legal if it is the result of performing executable actions
legal(s0).
legal(do(A,S)) :-
    legal(S),
    poss(A,S).
```

So thing is, when a consult done like follows ( `time()` only makes that the given answer returns the process time, for optimization sake... that's another problem i'll check later):

```
time((legal(S), holds(on(b,d),S), holds(on(c,b),S), holds(on(a,c),S), holds(color(b,blue),S), holds(color(a,red),S))).
```

SO far I get correct answers, but repeated like 10 times before it gives another, (correct too), so if I want all the answers, I've got to smash the ; like ten thousand times. I've been approximately 3 hours trying to solve this issue, since it doesn't let me check if I get all the correct answers or something is missing. Do you guys figure out what's going on?.
Tried to make everything as clear as possible, but comment if you need me to clarify something!

Comment: I haven't looked through your code in detail, but my general comment will be that if you get the same answer 10 times, that means that your logic allows the same answer to succeed 10 ways. You want to look for ways to make your rules more mutually exclusive, and that a single rule doesn't allow the same result to succeed in more than one way.

Comment: You sure this is the code you're using? There are a few syntax errors in it (line 37, no period; `holds/2` is discontiguous). What Prolog implementation are you using?

Comment: After playing with it for a few minutes, I don't have a solution for you, but I think the problem might be your whole approach. You're basically generating every possible thing that could happen, and then you winnow out things that have a negative effect. Your solution space is every possible action that could happen. You need to design a different algorithm that makes better use of your actual goal. Add a `trace(poss/2)` and then run your query and you'll experience the problem. I don't have a quick solution for you, which is a shame because it's such an interesting problem.

Comment: @DanielLyons I'm using SWI-prolog, the latest version. It gives a warning about the `holds` deifinition but runs anyway. Well buddy, you and I have tried to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, with a friend, we managed to fix it, the problem was on the positive conditional effects, specifically those related to `clear`. These affirmations were obvious, since a block must already return true to `clear` before being moved:

```
is_conditional_positive_effect(move_to_block(X,_),true,clear(X)).
is_conditional_positive_effect(move_to_table(X),true,clear(X)).
```

Also I changed some conditionals to be more specific, these greately improved the performance of the search:

```
is_conditional_negative_effect(move_to_table(X),on(X,_),on(X,_)).
```

was replaced by

```
is_conditional_negative_effect(move_to_table(X),on(X,Y),on(X,Y)).
```

and

```
is_conditional_positive_effect(paint(R,B,C),color(B,_),color(B,C)).
```

was replaced by

```
is_conditional_positive_effect(paint(R,B,C),true,color(B,C)).
```

Credits to my mate Pablo.